# setValue method error in firebase database creation (android studio0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, setvalue

I created a new project from scratch in android studio and tried connecting it to the firebase by following steps provided in help>firebase>database.

I got green checked for connecting app to firebase
but I  set up dependencies correctly .
however  I get setvalue method error.

I have attached a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For future questions, be sure to include the code as text in your question. Screenshots of text are seldom useful and reduce your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capitalisation is very important.

```
myRef.setvalue("Hello World"); // this will not work
myRef.setValue("Hello World"); // this will work
```

Comment: @sid.s please mark answer as correct for further reference.